# Issues with connections to database under low load (dotnet core)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linux, .net-core

I'm trying to load test a basic API, I've started getting some strange issues coming out of the database connection.
I've now narrowed it down to the SQL connection itself. (I'm using `SELECT 1` to test connection only)

under very low load (15 calls per second) everything works exactly as expected.

under low load (25 calls per second) the first 4-5 calls come back at an okay speed, then slowing down rapidly. A lot of calls timing out due to no connection in the pool.

under medium load (50 calls per second) everything locks up entirely, nothing comes back. And I start to get strange things like `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.` coming up. Cannot get a connection from the pool again.

`exec sp_who2` on the server shows no connections from dotnet either.

To make it worse the only way to recover from this is to bounce the entire service.

I have ruled out the server itself because this is happening on a powerful SQL server on-prem, an azureSql database, and a local service running on docker.

```
 int selected = 0;
 var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
 using (SqlConnection connection = CreateNewConnection())
 {
      try
      {
          connection.Open();
          selected = connection.QueryFirst<int>("SELECT 1");
          timer.Stop();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Failed connection");
          Console.WriteLine("fatal    " + e.Message);
          responseBuilder.AddErrors(e);
      }
      finally
      {
          connection.Close();
      }
 }

 responseBuilder.WithResult(new {selected, ms = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds});
```

I've even tried disposing, and forcing the connection close manually to understand what is going on.

This is running dotnet core, and dapper (I get the same issues even without dapper)

I've also tried upping the max connection pool limit to absurd numbers like 1000, and there was no effect.

**edit**

After trying a bit more, I decided to try with Postgres. Which works perfectly at over 1k calls per second. 
Am I missing something on in sql server itself? or on the connection?

Something to point out, These are shotgun calls. So a batch gets fired off as fast as possible, then wait for each request to return after.

Also this is using linux (and environments are docker k8s)

Someone wanted to know how connections got created

```
    private IDbConnection CreateNewConnection()
    {
        var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
        {
            UserID = "sa",
            Password = "012Password!",
            InitialCatalog = "test",
            DataSource = "localhost",
            MultipleActiveResultSets = true,
            MaxPoolSize = 1000
        };
        return new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
    }
```

**Another note**

Not shotgunning (waiting for the previous call to complete, before sending another) seems to have a decent enough throughput. It appears to be something with handling too many requests at the same time

**Version Information**
dotnet `2.1.401`
SqlClient `4.5.1`

Comment: Something to point out, These are shotgun calls. So a batch gets fired off as fast as possible, then wait for each request to return after.

Comment: Seems DBContext is created for call & is persisted for whole session. Can you show code from where you know how to connect database & which server to connect & that is persisted or instantiated every call

Comment: @StevenDall Update the question, don't add comments. As for missing something, I'd say you haven't provided all the code but it looks like `CreateConnection` is leaking connections. A connection pool is used so you *don't* need to reopen real connections to the server. When you call `Close()` or exit the `using` block the connection is reset and put back in the pool. You *wouldn't* get such a pool error if the connection was actually closed. PS: You don't need the `.Close()` here, it will be calles when execution leaves the `using` block.

Comment: @StevenDall you didn't mention what OS or .NET Core version you use. There could be a bug in the SqlClient library for Linux. On the other hand, connection pooling isn't new and 25 calls/sec is ridiculously low when you consider that you are reusing the *same* connection. Unless the connection string *disables* connection pooling ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is linux. I only started using `.Close() ` specifically because I ended up drawing at straws

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos also it's a new connection object every time if that makes a difference.

Comment: @StevenDall the important part is *Linux* and the actual version of .NET Core and the driver you use. It could be that the SqlClient library for *that* runtime doesn't handle connection pooling properly. .NET Core 1.0, 1.1, 2.0,2.1 ? 2.0 introduced huge changes and 2.1 added a ton of features and fixes.

Comment: Added the version Information

Comment: There's a [Github issue about a connection pooling bug](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14615) that affected all OSs and was fixed in SqlClient 4.5.0. Perhaps this is a regression, or a new bug? The discussion shows the problem was caused by improper use of the *ThreadPool*. The driver was stuck without actually opening connections, which would explain why you can't see any connections on the server's side. You should probably create a minimal program and try using it from Windows as well.

Comment: Notice that the discussion specifically mentions what you did : rapidly opening up connections to "warm" the connection pool. Perhaps you could mitigate the problem by setting  a minimum connection pool size in the connection string?

Comment: I don't have a windows box. But I know teammates do. I will ask them to run some tests. Unfortunately, that might only be Monday. But I will see what I can do until then. Thanks :)

Setting minimum connection pool didn't help either unfortunately

Comment: @StevenDall try removing `MultipleActiveResultSets`. I just tried this code on Window's Linux Subsystem. The *same* code with MARS on would take milliseconds on a Windows console but 8+ seconds inside WSL. With MARS false running on WSL went back to normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can verify something fishy is going on but it's probably not pooling. I created a console application and run it both from a Windows console and a WSL console on the same box. This way I was able to run the same code, from the same client but different OS/runtime.

On Windows, each connection took a less than a millisecond even with an absurd 500 DOP :

```
985 : 00:00:00.0002307
969 : 00:00:00.0002107
987 : 00:00:00.0002270
989 : 00:00:00.0002392
```

The same code inside WSL would take 8 seconds or more, even with a DOP of 20! Larger DOP values resulted in timeouts. 10 would produce results similar to Windows.

Once I disabled MARS though performance went back to normal :

```
983 : 00:00:00.0083687
985 : 00:00:00.0083759
987 : 00:00:00.0083971
989 : 00:00:00.0083938
992 : 00:00:00.0084922
991 : 00:00:00.0045206
994 : 00:00:00.0044566
```

That's still 20 times slower than running on Windows directly but hardly noticable until you check the numbers side by side.

This is the code I used in both cases :

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");

        var options=new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 500 };
        var watch=Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Parallel.For(0,1000,options,Call);
        Console.WriteLine($"Finished in {watch.Elapsed}");
    }

    public static void Call(int i)
    {            
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        using (SqlConnection connection = CreateNewConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                var cmd=new SqlCommand($"SELECT {i}",connection);
                var selected =cmd.ExecuteScalar();                    
                Console.WriteLine($"{selected} : {watch.Elapsed}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Ooops!: {e}");
            }
        }
    }

    private static SqlConnection CreateNewConnection()
    {
        var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
        {
            UserID = "someUser",
            Password = "somPassword",                        
            InitialCatalog = "tempdb",
            DataSource = @"localhost",
            MultipleActiveResultSets = true,
            Pooling=true //true by default                
            //MaxPoolSize is 100 by default
        };
        return new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need MARS, but I can potentially turn it off for now. I'll see if it helps, thanks.

Comment: @StevenDall why do you need MARS?

Comment: We have several connections that run in an async manner returning data at the same time. per http call. But we also have some transactions where some of the initial queries run at the same time, to prep for the last few queries that use them. With the requirement to roll it all back, something goes wrong. Tried to do some of them at the same time to save time on the call. Turned MARS off, and everything seems to be working as expected in the tests. We will change what needs to be changed to work around this for now

Comment: @StevenDall you don't (shouldn't) need MARS to use async queries. Again, there may be bugs in .NET Core that force you to use it. Normally, you'd need MARS if you wanted to fire multiple async queries on the same connection. That's a rather risky idea. You shouldn't need it to start a transaction, run a few async queries one after the other and then commit or roll back the transaction